# How can I run a script on shutdown?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian-squeeze

I have the following script, how do I run it on shutdown in Debian linux? (don't want to use GUI)

```
#!/bin/bash
vms=$(vmrun list | grep '/');
for vm in ${vms}
do
        echo 'suspending ' $vm
        vmrun suspend $vm soft
done
```

I tried adding it to `/usr/local/bin` with `chmod +x` permissions. Then I created symbolic links to rc0.d (shutdown) and rc6.d (reboot).

I then did `update-rc.d shutdown_vms 0 6`.

When I do `shutdown -r` now, it switches to console mode to restart - at that point I can see an error message stating `shutdown_vms has failed`.

I this the proper way to install the shutdown script and why is it failing (where do I look in the logs?)

Comment: Does the script work correctly if you do `sudo /etc/rc0.d/shutdown_vms stop` ?  Also, can you add an `exit 0` to the end of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please place your script into /etc/init.d/ and chmod +x it.
Then execute following command:

```
    update-rc.d yourscript start 0 6 .
```

How it looks after command execution:

```
    ll /etc/rc0.d/*yoursc*
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Jun 23 21:09 /etc/rc0.d/K01yourscript -> ../init.d/yourscript
    ll /etc/rc6.d/*yoursc*
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Jun 23 21:09 /etc/rc6.d/K01yourscript -> ../init.d/yourscript
```

Comment: can you update your answer with info using the symlink the OP is interested in ?